# How to send multiple data in AJAX call through PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send in multiple data where I am clicking on a couple of links back to back. Now here is the thing.

I have a 'share' link which if I click on gets the attribute as

```
$(".file").click(function(){ 
          var elementFile = $(this);
      var id = elementFile.attr("name");
});
```

Next, clicking on this link opens up a div (popDiv_share), which lists all the users from the database. Now if I click on any one of the user, I get its attribute just as above using:

```
$(".userlist").click(function(){ 
          var elementuser = $(this);
      var id = elementuser.attr("id");
});
```

Now what I am stuck with is say, I click on the first link, it gets the atrribute. Now when I click on the second link from the div, it gets the attribute too, but then the first link attribute is gone. How do I get both the attributes of each of the links even after clicking them back to back, since $(this) will only refer to the current link being clicked and the previous one will be lost.

Any suggestions would be of great help!!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['uid']; 
    include('db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * from registered_users";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_files_public where uid = $user_id");

?>      

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax-jaquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $(".file").click(function(){
    $(".userlist").click(function(){
      var elementUser = $(this);
      var elementFile = $(".file").$(this);

      var name = elementUser.attr("id");
      var id = elementFile.attr("name");

      var info='name='+name+'&id='+id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "share.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){
       }
     });
      $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
return true;
    });
  });
});

</script>

<style>

        .ontop_share {
        z-index: 999;
        width: 900px;
        height: 900px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;       
        background-color: #cccccc;
        color: #aaaaaa;
        opacity: 1.9;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
      }
      #popup_share {
        width: 900px;
        height: 900px;
        position: absolute;
        color: #000000;
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -150px;
      }

 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function pop(div) {
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
      }
      function hide(div) {
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
      }

</script>

   </head>

    <body>

<div id="popDiv_share" class="ontop_share">

<div id="popup_share">
      <?php

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name =$row['first_name'];?>

     <a href="" class="userlist" id="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id.' '.$name;?></a><?php  
    echo '<br/>';


  }
  ?>
  </div>  
            <a href="#" onClick="hide('popDiv_share')">Close</a>

</div>

    <table id="repos" align="center" cellspacing="20px">


            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th>Share</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


                   <?php

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $user_id = $row['uid'];
                    $filename =$row['user_file_name'];


           ?> 

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id ="actions"><?php echo $filename; ?></td>

            <td id ="actions">
                <a name="<?php echo $filename;?>" class="file" href="#" onClick="pop('popDiv_share')">Share</a>
            </td>


        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <?php     
          }                                
    ?> 
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a global variable:

```
 var name;
    $(".file").click(function(){ 
              var elementFile = $(this);
          name= elementFile.attr("name");


    });
    $(".userlist").click(function(){ 
              var elementuser = $(this);
            var id = elementuser.attr("id");
          $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "share.php",
         data: {
            name: name,
            id: id 
         },
         success: function(){
          }
         });

    });
```

or traverse the DOM:

```
$(".userlist").click(function(){ 
                var elementuser = $(this);
                var id = elementuser.attr("id");
                var name = $(this).closest('#popDiv_share').next('#repos').find('.file').attr("name");;
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "share.php",
             data: {
                name: name,
                id: id 
             },
             success: function(){
              }
             });

        });
```

Comment: actually you misunderstood. If you scroll down, there is a 'Share' link within <tbody> which has an attribute class="file". Now i click on this link, get its attribute using 
$(".file").click(function(){ 
          var elementFile = $(this);
      var id = elementFile.attr("name");
});

Clicking on this opens up a div which has a user list. I click on any of the users, and get the attribute the same way. I cant figure how to retain the attribute of the 'Share' link which I clicked earlier, since now it's gone due the the script referring to the $(this), which is the current click.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".file").click(function(){
    var elementFile = $(this);
    $(".userlist").click(function(){
       var elementUser = $(this);
       var name = elementUser.attr("id");
       var id = elementFile.attr("name");
       var info='name='+name+'&id='+id;
```

I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

You don need to use `&`  do something like

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "share.php",
        data: {
            name: name,
            id: id 
           },
        success: function(){
       }
     });
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variables attached to `window`, so you can reach them any time:

```
window.id;

$(".file").click(function(){ 
    var elementFile = $(this);
    window.id = elementFile.attr("name");
});
```

Once second link is clicked you can take that `global` variable and you it.

```
$(".userlist").click(function(){
    var id = window.id;
    // rest of code 
}
```